# Web Driver Selenium - Z-index Issue

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

i have to make a test on a pop-up, i'm using WebDriver Selenium in Python.

In few words if i open the pop-up, it goes under the overlay and it remains unclickable... but if i test this movement with WebDrivers Selenium everythings works.

```
popup = browser.find_element_by_id('help_paid_options')
if popup.is_displayed():
    print 'Found'
else:
     print 'Not Found'

popup.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='help_paid_options']/*  [contains(@class,'x_pop_close')]").click()

if popup.is_displayed():
     print 'Found'
else:
     print 'Not Found'
```

How can i test that a element is clickable (truly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Java** you could try do it this way. Just change the methods to how you would do it in Python.

**For FireFox and IE**
You could get the two z-indexs and check that the pop-ups is greater than the page elements it appears behind.

```
 //Get the elements you want to compare
 WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH For Panel"));
 WebElement elementTwo=driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH For Pop Up"));


 //Then get the values of the z-indexes 
 String zindex = element.getCssValue("z-index");
 String zindexTwo = elementTwo.getCssValue("z-index");
```

Then Parse the strings to int and compare that your pop up panel has a greater z-index

**Another Solution** is just to use the ChromeDriver as it cannot click on hidden elements

To use the **ChromeDriver**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

You can download the ChromeDriver from here http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Yes, this a way but i don't want test the "z-index factor" but the "unclickable factor" that can be generated by an other reason (in this case is "z-index" but in other case can be an overlapping of items).

There is a way to simulate the truly user interaction? Thanks

Comment: Sure! As u can see, in the code i call "click" to click on "x" for close the popup and everythings works but instead it shouldn't work because it's behind a overlay.

Comment: Missed that with it been off the screen. What browser Driver are you using. Do the others allow you to click it.

Comment: Yeah Chrome is awkward compared to Firefox. It might catch this problem as I have read it needs to be able to see the element to click it but they were talking about resolving this issue. I have included the install guide for chrome but you prob have it already

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

You can download the ChromeDriver from here http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Yes with Chrome everythings works, says: "Element is not clickable at point (884, 83). Other element would receive the click: nameElement".

Why Firefox doesn't work? :( And IE?

Comment: I am not sure all i could find on it that it was a fault with the Chrome Driver. But I would see it as a fault with the others the fact that they can click on something that's not visible. I will add the browser solution to my answer

Comment: This answer helped me in the way, that it's possible for one css class to be in the DOM several times. You can then determine via the z-index which is the topmost element!